# Generating and checking each element on combinations in an effective way

Tags: python, optimization, binary, combinations

I have a list of chars `chrs = ['A','B','C','D']`. I would like to loop through all and check combinations:

I would like to check every elements by the following order:

- First list: `A -> AB -> ABC -> ABCD -> ABD`
- Second list: `AC -> ACD`
- Third list: `AD`
- Fourth list: `B -> BC -> BCD`
- Fifth list: `BD`
- Sixth list: `C -> CD`
- Final list: `D`

My goal is to decrease the time I have to loop through all combinations. For example: If `A` doesn't have result, I won't check next strings `(AB -> ABC -> ABCD -> ABD)`. Because A is prefix of these next strings.

Can anybody recommend how can I do to make combination function faster? Because when I have more chars, I have to spend more time for my program